# I have facing issues in react website during seo optimization?

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing some issues related to react website during SEO optimization:

1. Complex indexing process, no other pages are index except home page after having sitemap
2. Not analytics friendly. Wrong URLs display on Google analytics like /www.abc.com/contact us
3. Through any tool, only single page can read through the tool.
4. In Google analytics wrong data have shown
   If anyone familiar with these things in react website then let me help and guide me.

Comment: Even though Google is capable of indexing them, React apps (and single page apps in general) rendered on the browser are not optimal for SEO. It'd be more SEO friendly to render your app on the server. Here are some tips to optimize your app https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-shares-seo-tips-for-single-page-apps/384100/

Comment: i don't know you have heard or not there is a term called `SSR` which stands for server side rendering,, please study about this and this will help you.. please check below link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering